Disable Google Photos backup prompt
I use Syncthing and restic to back up photos, so I don't need or want to use Google Backup.
When I open Google Photos, it periodically prompts me to turn on backup. If I say "no", the prompt comes back after a few days. Is there any way to permanently decline Google Backup?

It doesn't seem like this can be disabled in the builtin gallery, so I ended up installing an open-source gallery.
Fossify Gallery looks and functions a lot like the builtin gallery, but doesn't prompt me to backup photos over and over.
There seem to be a few other popular options such as aves and Gallery which I haven't tried.


First, open your Google Photos.
Then tap on your profile picture > Photos settings > Backup & sync.
Turn off Backup & Sync


Backup & Sync is off, but it keeps prompting me to turn it  on, and I can't view my photos until I've closed the prompt.

I also have turned off Backup & Sync and yet it still keeps pestering me to the point of getting rid of Google Photos.
